Rough estimate of the time until last photon radiated by object falling into black hole is seen by distant stationary observer
When an object falls into a black hole it takes an infinite amount of time according to a distant stationary observer until it reaches the horizon. From this point of view, such an observer will never actually see anything cross the horizon.
However, in practice, the light radiated by the falling object will be packaged into photons, which are emitted at discrete time intervals. (As a first-order approximation we can assume photons are emitted at a constant rate as a function of the proper time of the falling object.) Since the object crosses the horizon within finite proper time from its own point of view, there will evidently be a last photon that is emitted outside of the horizon. Hence, according to any distant observer, there will be a moment when the falling object has definitively disappeared from its view and cannot be seen anymore.
I'm interested in a rough order of magnitude estimate for the time interval as measured by a stationary observer at some radius (say a couple of Schwarzschild radii) between (I) the moment a radiating object is dropped radially from rest at that same radius, and (II) the moment the last radiated photon (assuming it is radiated in the right direction) arrives at the observer. For concreteness, assume, say, that the object radiates isotropically with a power of 100 W, and that the black hole is the one at the center of our galaxy.
I think the calculation is straightforward in a concrete scenario like this, but tedious. Has anyone ever calculated something along these lines, and if so, where can I find it?

Related but not the same: When a black hole is formed, photons fly off in all directions. Some are left in unstable orbit around the black hole. I remember reading that it takes less than 5 seconds for the last photon to spiral in or out. I don't have the reference.

The object might take a finite proper time to fall in, but an infinite coordinate time; it will continue to radiate, although increasingly less, until one of the black hole or the Universe or it no longer exists, no?

The number could be almost anything, depending on whatever the frequency of the signaling happens to be.

Note that the object would become invisible due to extreme redshifting, long before the last signal was emitted.

Your question overlooks one important fact. The time when the last photon is emitted is random and can be when the object is arbitrarily close to the horizon. Therefore there is no definite answer to your question and no estimate. Conceptually you can receive a dramatically redshifted photon any time in the future. You should make the question more specific. For example, how much coordinate time does a particle take to fall to within one Planck length off the horizon? Or when does the wavelength of the photon become larger than the  universe (or the solar system, etc.)?

Let us introduce a time interval characterizing a given black hole, Schwarzschild crossing time $\tau_\text{S}=r_\text{S}/c=2GM/c^3$. For black hole at the center of our galaxy, Sagittarius A*, this interval is about 42 seconds.
From the behavior of geodesics in the near  horizon region, we see that once the falling body is there, the distance between it and apparent  horizon decays exponentially with time of outside static observer: $(r-r_\text{S})\sim \exp(-\alpha t/\tau_\text{S})$, with dimensionless constant $\alpha$  of order $1$ (depending on specifics of motion). Similar law (but with time reversed) would be for a photon escaping the near horizon region. From this we can readily conclude that most relevant physical quantities characterizing observation of emitter falling into a black hole, such as observed frequency of radiation, total  power escaping to asymptotic region etc. would have exponential decay laws with comparable decay constants. So an estimate for the time of observability could only have one possible structure:
$$ T = \beta\, \tau_\text{S} \left|\log\left(\frac{f_e}{f_a}\right)\right|.$$
Here $\beta$ is a dimensionless constant of order $1$ (we would take a value of $2$ to account for the returnt travel time of photons, and the logarithm is of two physical quantities of the same nature one of which is characterizing emitter falling into the black hole and the other characterizes observer/detector.
For example, we can conclude that observer can register every individual photons (no matter how redshirted) and compare $N_e$ overall number of photons emitted during a $\tau_\text{S}$ interval to that one photon ($N_a=1$). Then, assuming $2\text{ eV}$ for the energy of individual photon:
$$N_e=\frac{100\text{ W }\tau_\text{S}}{2\text{ eV}}\approx 1.3× 10^{22}.$$
This gives the time interval of about one hour. After that time,  the chances that the one more photon will make an appearance  would be decreasing at exponential rate of one order of magnitude per several minutes.
Additionally, we can take Hawking radiation into consideration and conclude that after the radiation of falling emitter is redshifted so that its wavelength is much larger than $r_\text{S}$ there is no chance of distinguishing radiation of emitter from Hawking radiation. This gives us another estimate: assuming $\lambda_e=450\text{ nm}$ (blue light), $\lambda_a=r_\text{S}$, we obtain an estimate of $50$ minutes, remarkably similar to a previous number.
We can conjectre that the estimate of approximately $1$ hour for maximum interval of observability will stand, no matter how we tweak parameters of emitter and detectors.

Great answer +1 that is based on the condition of “no matter how redshirted” that leads to conclusions that may be misleading to a non-specialist. The answer makes it seem that objects falling to a black hole remain relevant outside for up to an hour with things changing minute by minute. Here is an article by a former member ChiralAnimaly: https://www.cphysics.org/article/51186 estimating that after one millisecond (!) the observable wavelength drops by 40 orders of magnitude while the observable power drops by 80 orders of magnitude - falling objects remain relevant only for microseconds.
